# Magento 1.9.2 - I do not want to show username, password, host and port in PHPMailer using SMTP

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email, smtp

At the moment we have this code to send emails with phpmailer via smtp. How can I make it work without showing **username**, **password**, **host** and **port**? I do not want to show my credentials in the file :

```
require_once "Mail.php";
$from = "myemail@email.com";
$to = "test@email.com";

$subject = "Test";
$body = "Hello";
$host = "mail.mysite.com";
$port = "myport";
$username = "myemail@email.com";
$password = "my_password";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo($mail->getMessage());
 } else {
  echo("success!");
 }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a Magento module you can create configuration variables which are set on the Configuration page and can be referenced in your code using syntax like:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/email/username');
```

Here's a tutorial on how to create configuration values 
https://inchoo.net/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/

If you aren't creating your own extension there are existing SMTP modules for Magento. A popular free one is aschroder's SMTP Pro extension.
https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension